# Broken pipe exception on rest web service in spring web application

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, glassfish

I am deploying a spring web application on glassfish server on raspberry(Raspbian os)...I  wrote a web service to get data from some sensors...this web service is using shared library(.so) to get temperature.(Beacause main library is c++ library ) But I get pipe broken exception....I searched and understand client close connection before server send response...But how can I solve this problem??

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/getdata", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public class temperatureController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/temp" , method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody
   float getTemperature(){

        NativeClass n = new NativeClass();
                   n.loadLib();
            float temp =  n.getTemperature(); // invoke the native method
        System.err.print(temp);
           return temp ;

   }
}
```

I get this exception:

```
[2016-05-30T10:33:13.460+0000] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.context] [tid: _ThreadID=41 _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [timeMillis: 1464604393460] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Exception when handling error trying to reset the response.
java.io.IOException: Connection is closed
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.NIOConnection.assertOpen(NIOConnection.java:432)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.OutputBuffer.flush(OutputBuffer.java:735)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flush(OutputBuffer.java:275)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.flush(CoyoteOutputStream.java:175)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:297)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlResponseWriter.endDocument(HtmlResponseWriter.java:442)
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.LayoutViewHandler.renderView(LayoutViewHandler.java:686)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:659)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at com.sun.webui.jsf.util.UploadFilter.doFilter(UploadFilter.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doChainInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:678)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.portunif.PUFilter.handleRead(PUFilter.java:231)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.portunif.PUFilter.handleRead(PUFilter.java:231)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:51)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOUtils.flushByteBuffer(TCPNIOUtils.java:149)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOUtils.writeSimpleBuffer(TCPNIOUtils.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOAsyncQueueWriter.write0(TCPNIOAsyncQueueWriter.java:126)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOAsyncQueueWriter.write0(TCPNIOAsyncQueueWriter.java:106)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.AbstractNIOAsyncQueueWriter.write(AbstractNIOAsyncQueueWriter.java:260)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.AbstractNIOAsyncQueueWriter.write(AbstractNIOAsyncQueueWriter.java:169)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.AbstractNIOAsyncQueueWriter.write(AbstractNIOAsyncQueueWriter.java:71)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransportFilter.handleWrite(TCPNIOTransportFilter.java:126)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.TransportFilter.handleWrite(TransportFilter.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$8.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.FilterChainContext.write(FilterChainContext.java:890)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.portunif.BackChannelFilter.handleWrite(BackChannelFilter.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$8.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.FilterChainContext.write(FilterChainContext.java:890)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ssl.SSLBaseFilter.handleWrite(SSLBaseFilter.java:363)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$8.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.FilterChainContext.write(FilterChainContext.java:890)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.portunif.BackChannelFilter.handleWrite(BackChannelFilter.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$8.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.FilterChainContext.write(FilterChainContext.java:890)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.FilterChainContext.write(FilterChainContext.java:858)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.OutputBuffer.flushBuffer(OutputBuffer.java:1029)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:681)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:355)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:342)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:161)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:221)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:291)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:295)
    ... 55 more
]]
```

Comment: Can you provide the full stack trace? I thinking that you get an `UnsatisfiedLinkError` but we need the full stack trace to verify.

Comment: I was getting that exception but now I think it is solved...ok, I will edit my post.

Comment: @Schrieveslaach : please tell me how can I see complete stack trace? in view raw log in admin console I can't see it...please help me

Comment: had another look on your stack trace. Are you sure that your code will be executed? Can you add some log statements?

Comment: @Schrieveslaach I am confused really!!I don't know how debug it without ide...I added some System.err.print and look at log file. Now I don't see any exception but just code will be executed until just before getTemerature()...I mean System.load and print after it executes.

Comment: Can you add `try { getTemperature(); } catch (Throwable t) { t.printStackTrace(); }` and post the output?